# How do I view GTFS data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, kml, general-transit-feed-specification

I would like to use QGIS to create my map. One data feed is the gtfs regarding to bus routes. I can view it on Google Earth (although laggy), but when I tried to import the .kml into QGIS, it just ran out of RAM (for 30 min) and crashed my map. If I import 10 in the 18xx layers, the route is duplicated 10 times (Google Earth could show all the routes, although laggy).

### My procedure

*I am trying a new method, so...*

What I did was download the .txt on TfNSW website (Google tfnsw data and login), then use a .py script called [Transitfeed](https://github.com/google/transitfeed) by bdferris to convert the .txt into .kml. Finally import the .kml as vector layers, but I did viewed in Google Earth prior that so I though it will be okay.

I am intended to convert the shape.txt into route shapes.

### Problem

I was thinking of the possibilities and solutions, for example:

1. Faulty .kml
2. Faulty .txt in the gtfs
3. Faulty conversion from .txt to .kml

I was thinking if either first two possibilities are valid, then what is the suitable validation (of my .kml) solution? Otherwise I would like a cost-less (i.e. monetary) solution for viewing gtfs .txt file into QGIS.

Comment: when I view the gtfs specification, it's all text files, and doesn't mention anything about kml. Is there something else you're doing with the gtfs file first? https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference

Comment: Sorry did nit mentioned that, I converted the txt to kml file. It is okay to view in Google Earth, but not QGIS.

Comment: Can you add how you converted the txt to kml, and add a link to a sample txt or kml file?

Comment: Please wait, I will do this in a minute...

Comment: Have you considered just using the .txt converting to .csv and then using the "Watch file" option in QGIS - if you're trying to stream the routes "live"?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not live data, will this makes a difference?

Comment: Ahhh...hold on - do you want a file of the routes? You need the TransXChange (TXC) file. That contains a .shp file of the routes, the GTFS file is the activity.

Comment: I'll try for TXC and see how it goes.

Comment: @AndrewTice I downloaded the TXC but only .xml, how to convert it to shapefile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From http://code.google.com/p/googletransitdatafeed/wiki/PublicFeeds, I took the data from TriMet Portland and had no problem adding the geometry data (stops.txt and shapes.txt) to QGIS with the MMQGIS plugin.

Once installed, use `MMQGIS -> Import/Export -> Geometry Import from CSV file`

Geometry Type `Point` for the stops and `Polyline`for the shapes.

If you experience the same laggy effect as with Google Earth, you might save the result to a spatialite database. Or store the data in a postgis database, as explained here:

http://opendesignarch.blogspot.de/2014/03/loading-gtfs-data-into-postgresql.html

https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/wiki/MMPTR-Tutorial

Comment: I did what you told and got a message: Invalid shape ID column: shape_id...
In addition, it is CSV not CSF.

Comment: Never mind, it's just means I have to change my field name to something like ID, lon, lat.

Comment: For the TriMet data, it worked fine. Maybe your file has some strange data.

Comment: No, for unknown reason, MMQGIS accepts ID, lat and lon as names.

Answer (score 3):

I have used the Points2One plugin and I found it pretty straight forward. 
https://youtu.be/cxAkTg_01vg

1 - Import GTFS file named 'shapes.txt' using 'Add limited Text Layer'

2 - Click on the Points2One plugin and create Lines by "shape_id"

Comment: Will try later, as this is 0200 at Sydney.

Answer (score 2):

I found this really nice tutorial by google search:

http://www.stevencanplan.com/2016/02/converting-a-transit-agencys-gtfs-to-shapefile-and-geojson-with-qgis/

I got my data here:
http://apps2.saskatoon.ca/app/data/google_transit.zip

In order to make the points into a path, it looks like the `Points to Path` plugin does not ship with qgis 3, but it also looks like qgis 3 comes bundled with a points to path tool thanks to another post I found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/241494/145631).

[image]