# How to convert multipoint attribute to polyline in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line, polyline-creation, multipoint

I have a multipoint layer in QGIS with 860 points.

Each points has some attributes value from a join, and I need to use one of those attributes (a column) to draw polylines. I need one polylines for each different value of that column (so 180 polylines)

Comment: Could you post a screenshot so we can see the shape of your multi-points clouds ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not so easy, because to efficiently convert points to lines (maybe  eventually to polygons), you need to have a criteria to link them, either **node order**, or **point cloud form**. Examples below.

Let's take 2 sets of multipoints.

- Make sure every multipoint entity has a unique ID
- Convert them into single points

[image: Points]

**Case 1** : entities are scattered in "easy shapes" like here. You can use a convex/concave hull or alpha shape to try and recreate the line going around,  doing a polygon at the end you can reconvert to a polyline. The problem with this method is that **the line might not pass through each points**...

[image: Convex hull 1]

[image: Convex hull 2]

**Case 2** **Entities are sequenced with a ID field in the desired line order**, and the software will be able to draw a line going from one point to another in the right order. If they have been digitalized or captured in the line order, you can fill a "Order" field with $id operator and use it to fill in the order field in the QGIS tool.

[image: Order field fill in]

[image: Path 1]
[image: Path 2]

Should they not be ordered, you might have this :

[image: Path bad]

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92751/draw-lines-from-points-in-qgis)

To add some visual:

[image]

The lines were created with he plugin **Points2one** based on the values I used in the representation/style of the points in the image. QGIS version 2.18.11.

The resulting line layer consists of polylines, so in my example the 3 green dots results in one polyline. If your multipoints do consist of multiple elements, you first might to convert your multipoints to single points with `Vector > Geometry tools > Multiparts to singleparts`.