# Number of buildings between two points

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS 2.18.13.

I have a polygon layer with building footprints, and a point layer with a given number of points. I would like to draw lines (randomly) between two points and see how many buildings the line crosses. How I can do that with QGIS?

Comment: I am not sure its random, but would this work for what you are after as a starting point: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92751/draw-lines-from-points-in-qgis… If you are able create the linking column as a  list of unique random numbers its worth a try. I gave it a shot, but it needs a further step to remove duplicates. Got to get back to  work :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach is through Virtual Layers / SpatiaLite syntax.

An example with 12 building and three points.

[image]

For illustration purpose add connecting lines between points with the Virtual Layer SQL:

```
select p1.id as id1, p2.id as id2, MakeLine(p1.geometry, p2.geometry) as geometryline
from point p1
cross join point p2
where p1.id <> p2.id
```

Use the Add / Edit Virtual Layer button:

[image]

In the QGIS Create a virtual layer dialog it looks like:

[image]

It will give you:

[image]

Add another virtual layer doing the complete query. Remember to rename the layer so you won't overwrite the first virtual layer:

```
with 
    crossinglines(geometry) as (
        select distinct MakeLine(p1.geometry, p2.geometry) as geometry
        from point p1
        cross join point p2
    )
    select distinct b.geometry 
    from building b
    inner join crossinglines cl on st_crosses(cl.geometry, b.geometry)
```

In the layer control context menu Show feature count for the last virtual layer - showing the number of buildings with a line crossing.

[image]

The lines of the first SQL are doubled. This is handled in the second SQL.

Notice that the virtual layers are dynamic to their base layers. Adding a point will recalculate the virtual layers when they are refreshed with the QGIS refresh button.

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:

Now for adding the building id to the building being crossed add a new virtual layer with the following SQL.

```
select v2.geometry, b.osm_id
from virtual_layer2 v2
inner join building b on st_equals(b.geometry, v2.geometry)
```

Where virtual_layer2 is you joined building layer that crosses the lines. Change the column name osm_id to your building id.

[image]

Comment: Thank youuuuuu a lot for your answer.. Now I can display the selected buildings an dcount the number of buildings between 2 points. Is it possible to display the Id of buildings as well ?

Comment: I updated the answer to include the building id.