# Create polyline layer from csv-file (id, lat, long, time) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, polyline-creation

Some *units* are moving and regularly registering it location. Each of these register events corresponds to row in a csv-file. This row contains fields:

- `id` (*unit* identifier),
- `lat`, `long` (event location),
- `time` (event time in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format, it can be a number of seconds from 1970 if it really matters)

I need to create a polyline layer in QGIS from this csv-file, that represent routes of the *units*.

Comment: Hi, did you try Points2One plugin mentioned here? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92751/draw-lines-from-points-in-qgis

Answer (score 2):

QGIS **Points to Path** tool understands Date/Datetime field as an order field.

So the overall steps are:

(1) From Menu `Layer | Add Layer | Add delimited text layer` to read csv into QGIS to create a point layer.

(2) From `Processing Toolbox | Vector creation (tools) | Points to path` to create polylines from this point layer. Your time field would be the `order field`. It understands Date and Datetime according to Python datetime format. If required, give format option (e.g. `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`), too.

Comment: As an alternative to the step (2) offered by [@Kazuhito](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84455/kazuhito), there is also a SAGA vector line tool, called [Convert Points to Line(s)](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.6/shapes_lines_1.html), where the `order field` requires string values of the time, it could be achieved with a `time.ctime([secs])` conversion.

Comment: @TarasDubrava Looks like your comment is proper answer!

Comment: [@Kazuhito](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84455/kazuhito), thanks, but I assume that my comment is it too poor to be a proper answer. However, I will try.