# Points from various sources to one line

Tags: qgis, points-to-line

I have "unsorted" points from various sources  - steming from a hiking track / path.

How can I create one line from the closest points (...following the track). I´ve already imported all points to one layer, but I´m not able to create a proper line.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The Points2One plugin for example? More on Points2One and some additional suggestions can be found in answers to this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92751/draw-lines-from-points-in-qgis

Comment: Try using a snapping algorithm (`v.snap` for instance) to snap the path to the points.

Comment: Thank you for your comments: Point2One ist not available for Qgis 3.8

Comment: I don´t have a line (path) so I can´t use snap tools

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using the `Distance matrix` tool and the `PointConnector` plugin. This is provided you have the points in one layer and that the goal is to connect by closest neighbours.

1. Start by creating a distance matrix for your point layer. Set both input and target layer to your points, set "Use only the nearest (k) target points" to 1 and save the result as a .csv file.
2. Then use the `PointConnector` plugin, setting "Point" to your point layer, and "From-to" to the distance matrix.

Here is a screenshot of the result of running the above steps on a few test points named "points", as seen in the layer tab. The steps taken have been outlined and numbered. 
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Came a big step forward! kr J