# Line along points with no continous ID and creation date/time

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, saga, points-to-line

I have a huge points file. The points are along a route network. I would like to build lines by going from point to point - but there is no chronology given!

The `"ID"`s seams to be chaotic and there is no date/time information.

How do I get lines from that layer?

[image]

Comment: What if you use one of the solutions offered in [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340601/points-from-various-sources-to-one-line), will it solve your issue?