# QGIS connect points by arrows and update automatically

Tags: qgis, point, line, points-to-line

I have a point layer with a date field and a text field. I want to create a layer with arrows that will connect them in order (and also group them by the text field). So far so good, the `Points to path` process does the trick. But I want new arrows to be automatically created each time I add new points.

Is there a solution that does not involve Python skills?

I have the feeling that [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/395911) geometry generator could help, but I'm failing to implement it.

Comment: If you are hoping for Python code help then please include a code attempt that illustrates what you’ve tried and where you’re stuck.

Comment: No, I didn't try Python. I tried the method linked to above, but by points are ordered by date, not by integer. So the attempt below could not work.